# Golang+PostgreSQL - How to print exact query without escape HTML tags?

Tags: postgresql, go

data stored in PostgreSQL: `The <b>Argentine Army</b> is`. Data type: `"content" text COLLATE "default"`.

When print through Golang, it become `The &lt;b&gt;Argentine Army&lt;/b&gt; is`

I need to print exact data from PostgreSQL without escaping HTML tags. I'm not sure if this is Go or PostgreSQL issue.

below is my Golang codes:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// type Gallery struct here
// type Template struct & function here

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    // DB connection here
    // Parse template & render here

    e.Get("/", func(c *echo.Context) error {

        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT uri, title, content FROM gallery WHERE id=123")
        // Handle error here

        gallery := []Gallery{}

        for rows.Next() {
            b := Gallery{}
            err := rows.Scan(&b.Uri, &b.Title, &b.Content)
            // Handle error here

            gallery = append(gallery, b)
        }

        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "onlytestingtpl", gallery[0])
    })

    e.Run(":4444")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by html template - you could use a function such as:

```
func unsafe(x string) template.HTML {
    return template.HTML(x)
}
```

to get the 'unescaped' html.

Comment: Is it comes from `unsafe` package? Because I'm using Echo framework, where should I place in my codes?

Comment: It comes from html/template package - I'm not familiar with Echo framework. I just named the function I wrote in the answer 'unsafe'. You should be able to put anywhere really and pass your Content string into it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still working to find the solution. I'm using `text/template` as temporary workaround.

Comment: @W.Mar The function you're looking for is this one: http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML - you need to apply a `template.FuncMap` to your template to mark the template as "safe". See here: http://technosophos.com/2013/11/23/using-custom-template-functions-in-go.html